# not able to create Foreign key in sql server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table like this:

`tblGender`

[image]

and `TblPerson`

[image]

I want to set foreign key for `GenderID`.. but I'm getting this error:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "tblPerson_GenderID_FK". The conflict occurred in database "Sample",
>   table "dbo.tblGender", column 'id'.

Comment: share the Create table scripts of both tabels

Comment: I created two tables Manually

Comment: Right click on the table ->script table as->Create To. will give the create script of the table.Check the answer i gave below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839309/the-alter-table-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 4):

You might have records in `tblGender` which don't have match in `tblPerson` on their respective columns.Try emptying the tables if that is an option.

Comment: Thanks Sir ...i added some record manually...i remove that..now ok..thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the script to add foreign key constraint.

```
alter table TblPerson
add constraint tblPerson_GenderID_FK FOREIGN KEY ( GenderID) references tblGender(id)
```