# query returns an exception with invalid column name

Tags: mysql, sql-server

i have 2 tables. Student and Bookings. Bookings contains an attribute StudNum which is reference to Students Primary key Student Number. However l cannot link StudNum with Student Number for it to become a primary key. The following error occurs.

> Unable to create relationship 'FK_LWAPBookings_Student'.   The ALTER
>   TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_LWAPBookings_Student". The conflict occurred in database
>   "C:\USERS\SINDI\DOCUMENTS\2017\IFS322E - SYSTEMS DEVELOPMENT
>   PROJECTS\SYSTEM\SYNERGINCE\SYNERGINCE\APP_DATA\TLC.MDF", table
>   "dbo.Student", column 'StudentNumber'

Comment: Is this MySQL or MS SQL? Looks to be MS SQL, but which ever it is, remove the other tag so that it is clear.

Comment: What is `FK_LWAPBookings_Student` linked to ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839309/the-alter-table-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint

Comment: If it was me, i would keep separate the student's public/external student no, and their private/internal 'student_id'

Comment: FK_LWAPBookings_Student is suppose to link the StudNum as a foreign key in the Bookings table and with the Primary key Student Number being in the Student table

Comment: Strawberry. How do you separate the them

Comment: Script out both tables with their PK, FK and update your question with these scripts