# How to apply a Entity Framework migration with foreign keys to a table with data

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have to apply a migration one of my coworkers added yesterday to my local DB:

```cs
public partial class addDocumentFK : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateIndex("dbo.DocumentHierarchy", "DocumentId");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.DocumentHierarchy", "DocumentId", "dbo.Document", "Id");
    }
    
    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.DocumentHierarchy", "DocumentId", "dbo.Document");
        DropIndex("dbo.DocumentHierarchy", new[] { "DocumentId" });
    }
}
```

The problem is that I already have data in my `Document` table and the migration fails:

```
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.DocumentHierarchy_dbo.Document_DocumentId". The conflict occurred in database "dgc_db", table "dbo.Document", column 'Id'.
```

Is there any way to avoid this conflict without having to wipe out all the data from the `Document` table?

Comment: Is it the same problem than this post ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839309/the-alter-table-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint
For me it sounds like you should remove the rows whose causing issues whit a not exists in the other table

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 scenarios:

1. You can remove the data from the Document table whose relationship cannot be found in the Document Hierarchy Table
2. You can add data with correct primary keys to the Document Hierarchy table so that the relationship is correct.

After performing any one of the above cases, you will be able to add foreign key via migration